# WPF Datagrid issue when adding rows (data not synced)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, initialization

I have a datagrid that I am populating with an object. Lets say customer and each customer holds an item. I have a button that adds a customer to the datagrid with a random item. If I keep adding customers to the datagrid to a point where the number of customers is more than the height of the datagrid (which causes the scroll to appear) the data beyond this point is not accurate until I press on it (to refresh it?).
I tested this by making my datagrid height bigger, as soon as I start inserting rows that dont appear in my view (until I scrolldown) the data doesnt seemed to be synced properly. I suspect this is a sync/initialization problem.

My datagrid xaml:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="706,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:CustomComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ItemsList, ElementName=MainWind}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

CustomComboBox

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Image at the side of the ComboBox -->
    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="0"
           Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>

    <!-- Actual ComboBox -->
    <ComboBox x:Name="CustomCombo" Grid.Column="1" 
              IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" KeyDown="CustomCombo_KeyDown"
              DropDownOpened="CustomCombo_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CustomCombo_DropDownClosed"
              Loaded="CustomCombo_Loaded"
              IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
              Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- StackPanel consisting of an Image and TextBlock as ItemTemplate-->
                    <Image Height="30" Width="30"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

I dont know the technical term of this problem to search for a solution.

Comment: Most likely the problem is due to virtualization. Try turning it off.

Comment: How do I do that? I dont think I have it turned on or is it turned on by default?

Comment: Try setting `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` .
Read about Attached Properties VirtualizingPanel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#attached-properties
And how the VirtualizingPanel interacts with the ItemsControl and its derivatives, including the DataGrid.

Comment: Your ComboBox has this binding ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ItemsList, ElementName=MainWind}", In your SelectedItem="{Binding Item, where is Item located? Does it have the same type as your DataContext.ItemsList? Have you tried to switch to SelectedValue instead?

Comment: @EldHasp virtualization didnt fix it. Is there a way to "refresh" the datagrid? It seems the values get corrected as I click on the datagrid so it seems its refreshing or something?

Comment: These are "subtle" nuances that can depend on many different reasons.
You need to run and debug the application.
Can you make a minimal example that reproduces this problem, upload it to GitHub and provide a link?

Comment: Will do and report back!

Comment: @EldHasp Here you go. https://github.com/melsawy93/WPFTestAppBug Run the application and select 10 items from the listview and press Add. They should be added in order Apple1 to Apple10. Press add several times if you dont see the bug instantly. You will see that the items are not correct. However pressing on any of the single combobox and closing it, the Text automatically corrects itself. Thanks alot for the help. You can also see the bug by adding a value several times. Try adding banana1 several times that the datagrid is filled and triggers the scroll.

Comment: @EldHasp please check the latest commit. Just noticed it wasnt there. Last commit is "Updated"

Comment: You have incorrectly implemented CustomComboBox.
The biggest mistake is changing the CLR setters of wrapper properties for Dependency Property. They should not have any logic other than `set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);`. You should also remove `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all related logic. The `Text` property should be implemented as a Dependency Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here you go. github.com/melsawy93/WPFTestAppBug

There are a lot of things wrong with this Repository.
First, the repository itself was created incorrectly. It should contain ignore and attribute files. Due to their absence, a lot of extra files got into the repository, including the .vs, bin, obj folders. Their presence adds a lot of imaginary changes at each commit.
Try creating a new empty Repository via the Git Visul Studio Menu. And you will see the ignore and attribute files there. Copy them to your Repository. And delete the extra folders in it using the CitHub Web interface.

I will post here the changes that need to be made to the source code:

**MainWindow.**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApp.MainWindow"
        ------------------
        ------------------
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

```xml
    <syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding FruitorVegie}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

```cs
        private MainViewModel _vm;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            SelectedFruitsOrVegie = new ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>();
            InitializeComponent();
            _vm = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        }
```

**CustomComboBox**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPFTestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomComboBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    ///
    public partial class CustomComboBox : CustomComboBoxBase
    {
        public CustomComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
    public partial class CustomComboBoxBase : UserControl
    {
        #region States
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemsSource",
                typeof(IEnumerable<IsFruitOrVegetable>),
                typeof(CustomComboBoxBase),
                new PropertyMetadata(null)
            );
        //private IsFruitOrVegetable[] defaultList = null;
        public IEnumerable<IsFruitOrVegetable> ItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable<IsFruitOrVegetable>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            }
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectedItem",
                typeof(IsFruitOrVegetable),
                typeof(CustomComboBoxBase),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((CustomComboBoxBase)d).OnSelectedItemChanged(e)) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true }
            );

        private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object e)
        {
            Text = SelectedItem?.Name;
        }

        public IsFruitOrVegetable SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (IsFruitOrVegetable)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Element name or filter text for the <see cref="ItemsSource"/> collection.
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Text"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(Text),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CustomComboBoxBase),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((CustomComboBoxBase)d).OnTextChanged((string)e.NewValue)) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

        private void OnTextChanged(string filterText)
        {
            if (itemsSourceViewSource.View is null)
                return;

            filterText = filterText?.Trim();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
            {
                itemsSourceViewSource.View.Filter = null;
            }
            else
            {
                itemsSourceViewSource.View.Filter = item => ((IsFruitOrVegetable)(item)).Name.IndexOf(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
            }
        }

        public CustomComboBoxBase()
        {
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, typeof(CollectionViewSource))
                .AddValueChanged(itemsSourceViewSource, OnItemsSourceViewChanged);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                itemsSourceViewSource,
                CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty,
                new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(ItemsSourceProperty), Source = this });
        }

        private void OnItemsSourceViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FilteredItemsSource = itemsSourceViewSource.View;
            OnTextChanged(Text);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The source for the filtered view of the ItemsSource collection.
        /// </summary>
        private CollectionViewSource itemsSourceViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

        /// <summary>
        /// A filtered view of the ItemsSource collection.
        /// </summary>
        public ICollectionView FilteredItemsSource
        {
            get => (ICollectionView)GetValue(FilteredItemsSourceProperty);
            private set => SetValue(FilteredItemsSourcePropertyKey, value);
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey FilteredItemsSourcePropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(FilteredItemsSource), typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(CustomComboBoxBase), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="FilteredItemsSource"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FilteredItemsSourceProperty = FilteredItemsSourcePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers
        private IsFruitOrVegetable lastSelectedItem;

        // Saves Last Selected Item when the drop down is opened
        protected void CustomCombo_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            comboBox.IsReadOnly = false;


            if (SelectedItem != null && SelectedItem.Type != FoodType.None)
            {
                lastSelectedItem = SelectedItem;
            }
            Text = "";
        }

        // Validates if Selected Item is of Type None, then it will revert back to 
        // the last selected Item which is saved
        protected void CustomCombo_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            comboBox.IsReadOnly = true;

            if (SelectedItem == null || SelectedItem.Type == FoodType.None)
            {
                if (lastSelectedItem != null)
                {
                    SelectedItem = lastSelectedItem;
                    Text = SelectedItem.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedItem = null;
                    Text = "";
                }
            }
            else if (SelectedItem != null && SelectedItem.Type != FoodType.None)
            {
                Text = SelectedItem.Name;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        protected void CustomCombo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            if (!comboBox.IsDropDownOpen && !(e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Escape))
            {
                comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<local:CustomComboBoxBase x:Class="WPFTestApp.CustomComboBox"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestApp"
             xmlns:cnvrt="clr-namespace:WPFTestApp.Converter"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFTestApp.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <cnvrt:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Image at the side of the ComboBox -->
        <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="0"
               Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>

        <!-- Actual ComboBox -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="CustomCombo" Grid.Column="1" 
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" KeyDown="CustomCombo_KeyDown"
                  DropDownOpened="CustomCombo_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CustomCombo_DropDownClosed"
                  IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
                  Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItemsSource}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- StackPanel consisting of an Image and TextBlock as ItemTemplate-->
                        <Image Height="30" Width="30"
                               Source="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</local:CustomComboBoxBase>
```

**P.S.** Keep in mind that I didn't fix all the bugs.
Changed only what matters for the solution of the question in the top of this topic.

Comment: Great. it seems to be working now. Thanks ALOT! The other bugs you refer to, any change you can just mention them (without fixing them) so I am aware of them. I am aware of the issue with the repo that was a mistake from my part.

Comment: @MElSawy , The most significant thing, in my opinion, is that the CustomComboBox should be a Custom Control from the ComboBox, not a UserControl.
The filter should be embedded in the Items.Filter property, rather than creating a separate collection view through the CollectionViewSource.
In the current implementation, there is a bug when entering a single letter for the first time - not all matching elements of the collection will be displayed.

Comment: Okay other than this bug, is there any particular benefit you see if this is inherited from ComboBox instead of UserControl? (just for my learning)

Comment: Errors concern the very approach to implementation. If you are doing this "for yourself", you are satisfied with his work, then use it as is. If this is a work task, and this element is intended for use by other developers of your team, then it must be implemented as it is customary for WPF and the maximally abstract. Otherwise, it will create difficulties with its use for other tasks.

Comment: Gotcha. The bug regarding the single letter is bugging me but its good to know that its not due to usercontrol/combobox. I will look into this as this is a small personal project but I certainly want to do it the "right" way.